# Read last line of file on sftp with Apache Camel

Tags: scala, apache-camel, sftp

When processing files from sftp directory using Apache Camel, i would like to get the last line of a csv file and populate the exchange header with it.

```scala
from("sftp://user@host/some/path?password=pass")
.filter{ m => m.in[RemoteFile[_]].getFileName.endsWith("_data.csv") }
.setHeader( "data", { m => /* here read last line of the file to get the data */ } )
```

I saw a GenericFile.getBody() that returns the content of the file, but i don't want to load the full file in memory. Ideally i would like to get a [ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html) and read the last line.

I'm using apache camel 2.17 (camel-core, camel-ftp and camel-scala)

Comment: Then write some java code that reads the last line and return it from a method, then you set a header by calling the method.

Comment: Yes of course i can do it my self but i will need to recreate new sftp connection etc ... I thought there was a simpler way, at least something to reuse the sftp channel to read the remote file.

Comment: The file is already downloaded. If you want to filter on the server side, then use the filter option on the FTP endpoint, not the filter EIP.

Comment: Thank you, yes i'm already using the server side filtering, i only need to extract some data without downloading the file.

Comment: What is the destination dir ? Didn't found it in documentation.
I've added the "&streamDownload=true" option to the uri but the body of the RemoteFile that i get is still com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2@609912f5
How to get an InputStream ?